# Is the following probability statement about random variables true?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a random variable.

Suppose that $A \in \mathcal{R}$, the Borel sets of the real numbers and for every $a \in A$ we have $\mathbb{P}\{X=a\} = 0$. Is it true that $\mathbb{P}\{X \in A  \} = 0$?

I have trouble proving this due to the possible uncountability, so I am thinking it might be false. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If $A$ is countable and $P(X=a)=0$ for every $a\in A$ then $P(X\in A)=\sum_{a\in A}P(X=a)=0$. But that does not work if $A$ is uncountable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

If $X$ has continuous distribution (i.e. its CDF is continuous) then $\mathsf P(X=x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$.

Nevertheless $\mathsf P(X\in\mathbb R)=1$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Consider a random variable that is uniformly distributed in $A=[0,1]$.